# Minimum number of edges to describe a polyedron

Tags: geometry

Consider the triangle below

[image]

It appears to me that one can describe this geometry minimally, in terms of edges, by e1 and e2. Therefore, information about e3  would be redundant. Is this true? Is there any proof of this claim?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you ever drawn circles of various sizes using a [compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_(drawing_tool))?

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the length 0f $e_3$ you must pick the angle of $v_3$ instead.